# PG Admin 4 Restore Windows Order

Tags: pgadmin-4

I broke the order of windows and cannot restore them. How do I put them in the default state at the bottom of the screen?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File -> Reset Layout. Pretty simple))